# Quality profile neutral change raises too many new issues

Tags: sonarqube

We previously directed changed rules in the default sonar way quality profile.
To better track the changes made I created a new one which inherited the default one. 
I then restore the built-in profile and reapplied out change in our new profile.

But after a new analysis we now have lot of issues reported as new.

Did I do something wrong ?

thanks for some explanation.

---

SonarQube Version 5.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default contents of the Sonar Way quality profile, can change from version to version as new rules are implemented, altho upgrading a plugin does not automatically add those new rules to an existing Sonar Way profile because of exactly what you saw. So your restoration pulled in all the rules that have been added to the profile since you first started with the plugin (or since the last time you performed a restoration). Additionally, new plugin versions may improve the implementations of existing rules, so new issues can show up after an upgrade even if you don't do a restore.

The restoration is why a lot of new issues were added on your subsequent analysis.